# Where is the default home page in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It says "Yay! You're on Rails!"

I can't find the word `yay` anywhere in the project folder. I am surely missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's default page of rails > 5.0 version.

rails auto install `railties` gem while creating project and this gem contain static template of welcome page.

you can find page under `../gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb`

you can find more detail [Here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/railties/5.1.5)